# Form Submit Button Works, but not Submit() in Link

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I've done this so often before on different websites, but can't get it to work now.
I've got a simple form that posts perfectly well using a submit button, but for a specific reason I actually need it to submit via a url link instead.  I'm using `submit()`.  The form submits, but the data isn't posting.
What am I missing?

```
<html>
<body>
<?
if(isset($_POST['bar'])) { echo 'testing button<br>'; }
if(isset($_POST['information'])) { 
    echo $_POST['information'];
    echo '</br>Info successfully posted.'; 
    }
?>

    <form action="test.php" method="post" id="fooform"> 
        Hello World.<br>
        Select checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="information" name="information" value="yes">
        <input type="submit" name="bar" value="Send"><br>
        <a href="test.php" onclick="SubmitForm('fooform');">Confirm and Post</a><br>
        <a href="test.php" onclick="this.form.submit();">Post Directly </a>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SubmitForm(formId) {
            var oForm = document.getElementById(formId);
            alert("Submitting");
            if (oForm) { oForm.submit(); }
            else { alert("DEBUG - could not find element " + formId); }
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think you need to use get instead of post

Comment: @mostafakhansa — What makes you think that?

Comment: "Select checkbox:" should be in a `<label>` and to the *right* of the checkbox. See http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Answer (score 3):

The form starts to submit, then the `href` of the link is followed, and this cancels the form submission.

If you are using old-style `onclick` attributes, then `return false;` at the end to prevent the default action.

You would, however, be better off using a submit button (you **are** submitting a form). You can use CSS to change its appearance.

Comment: Even a *button* button (`<button type="button">`) would be more appropriate than an `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code :**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['bar'])) {
            echo 'testing button<br>';
        }
        if (isset($_POST['information'])) {
            echo $_POST['information'];
            echo '</br>Info successfully posted.';
        }
        ?>

        <form action="test.php" method="post" id="fooform"> 
            Hello World.<br>
            Select checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="information" name="information" value="yes">

            <input type="submit" name="bar" value="Send"><br>
            <a href="#" onclick="SubmitForm('fooform');">Confirm and Post</a><br>
            <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('fooform').submit();">Post Directly </a>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
                function SubmitForm(formId) {
                    var oForm = document.getElementById(formId);
                    alert("Submitting");
                    if (oForm) {
                        oForm.submit();
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("DEBUG - could not find element " + formId);
                    }
                }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

try to submit form with form id in jquery

```
<a class="submit">Post Directly </a>

$('a.submit').click(function(){

   $('#fooform').submit();
})
```

Comment: can i know what for downvoting?

Comment: maybe for a href link wich i had just copied, just for mention a class a have added, and forgot to remove href attr and onclick?